find the optimal value from a lagrangian
I am trying to understand the algorithm in this paper, https://experts.illinois.edu/en/publications/cluster-analysis-of-longitudinal-profiles-with-subgroups.
In the paper, the Lagrangian is
$$Q(\beta)+\sum_{l}\rho(\lVert v_l\rVert_2,\lambda_2)+\frac{\theta}{2}\sum_{l}\lVert\beta_i-\beta_j-v_l\rVert_2^2+\sum_{l}\lambda_l^T(v_l-\beta_i+\beta_j)$$
where $\rho(\lVert v_l\rVert_2,\lambda_2)=\lambda_2\int_0^{\lVert v_l\rVert_2}\left(1-\frac{x}{\tau\lambda_2}\right)_+dx$.
I am struggling to find the optimal for $v_l$. So far, I have $v_l=\beta_i-\beta_j-\lambda_l/\theta$ when $\lVert v_l\rVert_2\geq\tau\lambda_2$. For the opposite direction, I have
$$\lambda_2\left(1-\frac{\lVert v_l\rVert_2}{\tau\lambda_2}\right)v_l-\lambda_2-\theta(\beta_i-\beta_j-v_l)+\lambda_l=0$$
I couldn't manage to get the form on the paper, that is
$$\frac{\tau\theta}{\tau\theta-1}\left(1-\frac{\lambda_2/\theta}{\lVert\beta_i-\beta_j-\lambda_l/\theta\rVert_2}\right)(\beta_i-\beta_j-\lambda_l/\theta)$$
Any help is appreciated.
